# Need the update to always run

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using Actionscript 3 and not doing classes, only the actionscript for each panel. I'm trying to make a character creation screen that tells the player how many points they have left after they add them to one of six categories. The score is working, BUT the part that updates the player as to how many points they have left ISN'T. I need it to constantly update to tell the player how many points are left.

```
var score=0;
var strscore=1;
scorenum.text= update(score); //How I want it displayed.

function update(score)   //Brings in the score variable
{
    while(score<66)  //As you can see I'm trying to make it constantly call here. 
                     //No Good. Calls once.
{
trace("update Score "+score)
var num= 65-score;
scorenum.text= num;
return num;
}

}

strMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, strMinusFn);
function strMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{   
if (score<=59)
{
    if (strscore >1 && strscore<=50)
    {
        strscore--;
        score--;
    }
    else
    {
        strscore==strscore;
    }
}
    sX.text=strscore;

    return score;
}
strPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, strPlusFn);
function strPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=58)
{
    if (strscore >=1 && strscore<50)
    {
        strscore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        strscore==strscore;
    }
}
    sX.text=strscore;

    return score;
}

var dexscore=1;
dexMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dexMinusFn);
function dexMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)

{
if (score<=59)
{
    if (dexscore >1 && dexscore!=50)
    {
        dexscore--;
        score--;
    }
    else
    {
        dexscore==dexscore;
    }
    dX.text=dexscore;
}
return score;

}
dexPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dexPlusFn);
function dexPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=58)
{
    if (dexscore >=1 && dexscore<50)
    {
        dexscore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        dexscore==dexscore;
    }
    dX.text=dexscore;
}
return score;

}

var intscore=1;
intMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, intMinusFn);
function intMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=59)
{
    if (intscore >1 && intscore!=50)
    {
        intscore--;
        score--;
    }
    else
    {
        intscore==intscore;
    }
    iX.text=intscore;
}
return score;

}
intPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, intPlusFn);
function intPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=58)
{
    if (intscore >=1 && intscore<50)
    {
        intscore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        intscore==intscore;
    }
    iX.text=intscore;
}
return score;

}

var conscore=1;
conMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conMinusFn);
function conMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=59)
{
    if (conscore >1 && conscore!=50)
    {
        conscore--;
        score--;
    }
    else
    {
        conscore==conscore;
    }
    cX.text=conscore;
}
return score;
} 

conPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conPlusFn);
function conPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=58)
{
    if (conscore  >=1 && conscore<50)
    {
        conscore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        conscore==conscore;
    }
    cX.text=conscore;
}
return score;
}

var wisscore=1;
wisMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wisMinusFn);
function wisMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=59)
{
    if (wisscore >1 && wisscore!=50)
    {
        wisscore--;
         score--;
     }
    else
     {
        wisscore==wisscore;
    }
    wX.text=wisscore;
}
return score;
}
wisPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wisPlusFn);
function wisPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=58)
 {
    if (wisscore  >=1 && wisscore<50)
    {
         wisscore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        wisscore==wisscore;
    }
    wX.text=wisscore;
}
 return score;
}

var chascore=1;
chaMinus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chaMinusFn);
function chaMinusFn(event:MouseEvent)
{
if (score<=59)
{
    if (chascore >1 && chascore!=50)
    {
        chascore--;
        score--;
    }
    else
    {
        chascore==chascore;
    }
    hX.text=chascore;
}
return score;
}
chaPlus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chaPlusFn);
function chaPlusFn(event:MouseEvent)
 {
if (score<=58)
{
    if (chascore  >=1 && chascore<50)
    {
        chascore++;
        score++;
    }
    else
    {
        chascore==chascore;
    }
    hX.text=chascore;
}
return score;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a while loop that will update the remainder every time you put a score into a "attribute".

Something along the lines of

```
while score > 0
     if attribute_variable > variable_counter
           score -= 1
           variable_counter += 1
```

So the while loop will check if you have any score to put into your attributes. The if statement will be checking to see if you put a point into the specific attribute and the statements inside the if are to update the score and the counter for that specific counter so that the counter recognizes you have put a point into that variable.